# IF statement with Transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I execute my transact SQL code

```
IF (SELECT model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357') IS NULL
    SELECT part_id FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
ELSE
     SELECT model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357'
```

I receive the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just using `COALESCE()`?

```
SELECT COALESCE(model_id, part_id)
FROM request_unit 
WHERE request_id = '4357';
```

The `IF` is not needed.

The error itself seems pretty self-explanatory.  There is more than one row in `request_unit` where the `request_id` is 4357.

Comment: It works well thank you, but the header of the results table is not showing the name of the column (model_id or part_id). It shows 'No column name'

Comment: @NaderLaroussi just alias it, like ( model_id ModelID, part_id PartID)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

It means there are several `model_id` for the `request_id = '4357'`

```
IF Not Exists (SELECT model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357')
    SELECT part_id FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
ELSE
     SELECT model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  IF (SELECT top 1 model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357') IS NULL
    SELECT part_id FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
ELSE
     SELECT model_id FROM request_unit where request_id = '4357'
```

This too can be used, but the @Gordon Lioff's answer is preferred

Answer (score 0):

Along with @GordonLinoff's answer you can write the following in order to get the column name:

```
SELECT COALESCE(model_id, part_id) as 'YOURCOLUMNNAME'
FROM request_unit 
WHERE request_id = '4357';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like;

[COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
SELECT COALESCE(model_id, part_id) FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
```

[ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

```
SELECT ISNULL(model_id, part_id) FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
```

[CASE WHEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN model_id IS NULL THEN part_id ELSE model_id END FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
```

[IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) `Starting with 2012`

```
SELECT IIF(model_id IS NULL, part_id, model_id) THEN part_id ELSE model_id END FROM request_unit WHERE request_id = '4357'
```